# Javadoc Multi-Line Declaration Syntax?

Tags: java, file, path, javadoc

If I have the variable declaration:

```
/**
 * The Resource folder for the program Information.
 */
public static final Path RESOURCE_FOLDER_PATH = Paths.get("", "Resources"),
/**
 * The folder holding all faction information.
 */
FACTION_FOLDER_PATH = Paths.get(RESOURCE_FOLDER_PATH.toString(), "Faction Information");
```

The Javadoc will not document the latter Path variable. Does Javadoc support this type of documenting style or do I have to declare them separately?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that javadoc works on variable *declarations*, not variable assignments.

Comment: Those _are_ declarations.  See the comma after the first one?

Comment: I think you've actually discovered the answer for yourself.  You've said that this doesn't work in Javadoc, then asked whether Javadoc supports it.  In all honesty, I think you should avoid this style of code.  It's not very clear that the second declaration is in fact a declaration, not an assignment.  I can just imagine, at some future date, someone will come along and try to insert another declaration, of another type, between these two, and thus break everything.  So, regardless of what Javadoc will or won't do, in the interests of readability and maintainability, I strongly recommend ...

Comment: ... making every variable declaration separate and stand-alone.  Don't use commas in this way, and definitely don't split declarations across multiple lines like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No unfortunately you can't.

You need to do it in the following way which is clearer and neater:

```
/**
 * Returns an Image object that can then be painted on the screen. 
 * The url argument must specify an absolute {@link URL}. The name
 * argument is a specifier that is relative to the url argument. 
 * <p>
 * This method always returns immediately, whether or not the 
 * image exists. When this applet attempts to draw the image on
 * the screen, the data will be loaded. The graphics primitives 
 * that draw the image will incrementally paint on the screen. 
 *
 * @param  url  an absolute URL giving the base location of the image
 * @param  name the location of the image, relative to the url argument
 * @return      the image at the specified URL
 * @see         Image
 */
 public Image getImage(URL url, String name) {
        try {
            return getImage(new URL(url, name));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            return null;
        }
 }
```

Comment: ... Surely a shorter example would have sufficed, and likely been more targeted to the question?